# Zoom in Teams by less than 20% steps

Tags: microsoft-teams, zoom, windows-11-v22h2

Regardless of the zoom method used in Teams (i.e., "three-dot-menu", CTRL+Mouse or CTRL++) it always zooms in 20% steps. Is there a way to do this in like 5% steps? Otherwise the text is either too <sub>tiny</sub> or too HUGE!

Comment: I can't find any, using Windows 10 here. Every option, including the zoom slider goes in increments of 20%.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for trying! It's a little bit comforting to know that it's not only my app that's _misbehaving_.

Comment: You can try the web version. I bet your browser has more zooming steps.

Comment: Using v"1.6.00.18681 (64-bit). It was last updated on 13/07/2023", mine zooms in 15% increments. And I can no longer use ctrl+scroll (mouse wheel) to zoom in/out.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Teams zoom levels are built-in and cannot be customized
(at least at the moment).

The minimum is 60% and the maximum is 200%.
You can cycle through following steps, one at a time :
60, 70, 85, 100, 120, 145, 170, 200.

Comment: It's absolutely ridiculous to hardcode such zoom steps :-\

Comment: @t3chb0t: The whole UI of Teams looks hard-coded and the separators between sections are unmovable. I don't know what software it was written with, apparently not with a modern development environment such as Qt where this is automatic.

Comment: I thought it was Electron like other similar apps, but I cannot find any way to open the dev console as with Ctrl+Shift+I in GitHub Desktop, but Teams seems to be some .net thingy. At least it's packaged as .nuget and contains a lot of .net assemblies. Unfortunatelly the main app is compiled into one huge exe (after you extract the .nuget since it's just a .zip).

Comment: Has anyone found where the setting is saved? Maybe we can change it in there and restart Teams.

Comment: @Vladimir: It's built-in to the executable.

Comment: The value of the zoom setting must be saved somewhere in the configuration file on the file system. There must be a way to edit it manually.